# expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality in npm test, string when changes line adds a “.” in the end in the returned string

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, npm, gulp-npm-test

I am making a program for a todo list using python 3 and it has a help function which prints on console following:

```
Usage:-
    $ ./todo add "todo item"  # Add a new todo
    $ ./todo ls               # Show remaining todos
    $ ./todo del NUMBER       # Delete a todo
    $ ./todo done NUMBER      # Complete a todo
    $ ./todo help             # Show usage
    $ ./todo report           # Statistics
```

When I run npm test on it. The test case shows the following message:

```
FAIL ./todo.test.js (13.527 s) × prints help when no additional args are provided (277 ms) × prints help (238 ms) √ add a single todo (237 ms) √ show error message when add is not followed by a todo (237 ms) √ add multiple todos (750 ms) × list todos in reverse order (added latest first) (1000 ms) √ list when there are no remaining todos (230 ms) √ delete a todo (972 ms) √ delete todos numbered 3, 2 & 1 (1426 ms) √ delete first todo item 3 times (1438 ms) √ delete non-existent todos (1440 ms) √ delete does not have enough arguments (251 ms) √ mark a todo as done (956 ms) √ mark as done a todo which does not exist (953 ms) √ mark as done without providing a todo number (945 ms) × report pending & completed todos (1466 ms)

● prints help when no additional args are provided

expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: StringContaining "Usage :-
$ ./todo add \"todo item\"  # Add a new todo
$ ./todo ls               # Show remaining todos
$ ./todo del NUMBER       # Delete a todo
$ ./todo done NUMBER      # Complete a todo
$ ./todo help             # Show usage
$ ./todo report           # Statistics"
Received: "Usage:-·
    $ ./todo add \"todo item\"  # Add a new todo·
    $ ./todo ls               # Show remaining todos·
    $ ./todo del NUMBER       # Delete a todo·
    $ ./todo done NUMBER      # Complete a todo·
    $ ./todo help             # Show usage·
    $ ./todo report           # Statistics·
"

  26 |   let received = execSync(todoTxtCli()).toString("utf8");
  27 |
> 28 |   expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(usage));
     |                    ^
  29 | });
  30 |
  31 | test("prints help", () => {

  at Object.<anonymous> (todo.test.js:28:20)
● prints help

expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: StringContaining "Usage :-
$ ./todo add \"todo item\"  # Add a new todo
$ ./todo ls               # Show remaining todos
$ ./todo del NUMBER       # Delete a todo
$ ./todo done NUMBER      # Complete a todo
$ ./todo help             # Show usage
$ ./todo report           # Statistics"
Received: "Usage:-·
    $ ./todo add \"todo item\"  # Add a new todo·
    $ ./todo ls               # Show remaining todos·
    $ ./todo del NUMBER       # Delete a todo·
    $ ./todo done NUMBER      # Complete a todo·
    $ ./todo help             # Show usage·
    $ ./todo report           # Statistics·
"

  32 |   let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("help")).toString("utf8");
  33 |
> 34 |   expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(usage));
     |                    ^
  35 | });
  36 |
  37 | test("add a single todo", () => {

  at Object.<anonymous> (todo.test.js:34:20)
● list todos in reverse order (added latest first)

expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: StringContaining "[3] find needle in the haystack
[2] water the plants
[1] the thing i need to do
"
Received: "[3] find needle in the haystack·
[2] water the plants·
[1] the thing i need to do·
"

  80 |   let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("ls")).toString("utf8");
  81 |
> 82 |   expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
     |                    ^
  83 | });
  84 |
  85 | test("list when there are no remaining todos", () => {

  at Object.<anonymous> (todo.test.js:82:20)
● report pending & completed todos

expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: StringContaining "2020-12-22 Pending : 1 Completed : 2"
Received: "2020-12-23 Pending : 1 Completed : 2·
"

  216 |   let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("report")).toString("utf8");
  217 |
> 218 |   expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
      |                    ^
  219 | });
  220 |

  at Object.<anonymous> (todo.test.js:218:20)
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total Tests: 4 failed, 12 passed, 16 total Snapshots: 0 total Time: 14.546 s Ran all test suites. npm ERR! code 1 npm ERR! path C:\Users\shubh\Desktop\TODO\python npm ERR! command failed npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c jest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\shubh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2020-12-22T19_06_10_509Z-debug.log
```

I am not able to understand why there is a "." sign added at the end of every line. This is the console output which is coming same as the expected output. console output

Please help me troubleshoot it.
This is the code for help fxn:(Language: python 3)

```
   def help():
    print('''Usage:-
    $ ./todo add "todo item"  # Add a new todo
    $ ./todo ls               # Show remaining todos
    $ ./todo del NUMBER       # Delete a todo
    $ ./todo done NUMBER      # Complete a todo
    $ ./todo help             # Show usage
    $ ./todo report           # Statistics''')
```

I've tried doing it using different print statements as well but no luck/
Below is the todo.test.js file code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { execSync } = require("child_process");

let deleteFile = (path) => {
  try {
    fs.unlinkSync(path);
  } catch (err) {}
};

beforeEach(() => {
  deleteFile(`${__dirname}/todo.txt`);
  deleteFile(`${__dirname}/done.txt`);
});

let todoTxtCli = (...args) => [`${__dirname}/todo`, ...args].join(" ");

let usage = `Usage :-
$ ./todo add "todo item"  # Add a new todo
$ ./todo ls               # Show remaining todos
$ ./todo del NUMBER       # Delete a todo
$ ./todo done NUMBER      # Complete a todo
$ ./todo help             # Show usage
$ ./todo report           # Statistics`;

test("prints help when no additional args are provided", () => {
  let received = execSync(todoTxtCli()).toString("utf8");

  expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(usage));
});

test("prints help", () => {
  let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("help")).toString("utf8");

  expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(usage));
});

test("add a single todo", () => {
  let expected = 'Added todo: "the thing i need to do"';
  let received = execSync(
    todoTxtCli("add", '"the thing i need to do"')
  ).toString("utf8");

  expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
});

test("show error message when add is not followed by a todo", () => {
  let expected = "Error: Missing todo string. Nothing added!";
  let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("add")).toString("utf8");

  expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
});

test("add multiple todos", () => {
  let todos = [
    "the thing i need to do",
    "water the plants",
    "find needle in the haystack",
  ];

  todos.forEach((todo, i) => {
    let expected = `Added todo: "${todo}"`;
    let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("add", `"${todo}"`)).toString("utf8");

    expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
  });
});

test("list todos in reverse order (added latest first)", () => {
  let todos = [
    "the thing i need to do",
    "water the plants",
    "find needle in the haystack",
  ];
  todos.forEach((todo) => execSync(todoTxtCli("add", `"${todo}"`)));

  let expected = `[3] find needle in the haystack
[2] water the plants
[1] the thing i need to do
`;
  let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("ls")).toString("utf8");

  expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
});

test("list when there are no remaining todos", () => {
  let expected = `There are no pending todos!`;
  let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("ls")).toString("utf8");

  expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
});

test("delete a todo", () => {
  let todos = [
    "the thing i need to do",
    "water the plants",
    "find needle in the haystack",
  ];
  todos.forEach((todo) => execSync(todoTxtCli("add", `"${todo}"`)));

  let expected = "Deleted todo #2";
  let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("del", "2")).toString("utf8");

  expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
});

test("delete todos numbered 3, 2 & 1", () => {
  let todos = [
    "the thing i need to do",
    "water the plants",
    "find needle in the haystack",
  ];
  todos.forEach((todo) => execSync(todoTxtCli("add", `"${todo}"`)));

  [3, 2, 1].forEach((n) => {
    let expected = `Deleted todo #${n}`;
    let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("del", n.toString())).toString("utf8");

    expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
  });
});

test("delete first todo item 3 times", () => {
  let todos = [
    "the thing i need to do",
    "water the plants",
    "find needle in the haystack",
  ];
  todos.forEach((todo) => execSync(todoTxtCli("add", `"${todo}"`)));

  [1, 1, 1].forEach((n) => {
    let expected = `Deleted todo #${n}`;
    let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("del", n.toString())).toString("utf8");

    expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
  });
});

test("delete non-existent todos", () => {
  let todos = [
    "the thing i need to do",
    "water the plants",
    "find needle in the haystack",
  ];
  todos.forEach((todo) => execSync(todoTxtCli("add", `"${todo}"`)));

  [0, 4, 5].forEach((n) => {
    let expected = `Error: todo #${n} does not exist. Nothing deleted.`;
    let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("del", n.toString())).toString("utf8");

    expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
  });
});

test("delete does not have enough arguments", () => {
  let expected = "Error: Missing NUMBER for deleting todo.";
  let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("del")).toString("utf8");

  expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
});

test("mark a todo as done", () => {
  let todos = [
    "the thing i need to do",
    "water the plants",
    "find needle in the haystack",
  ];
  todos.forEach((todo) => execSync(todoTxtCli("add", `"${todo}"`)));

  let expected = "Marked todo #2 as done.";
  let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("done", "2")).toString("utf8");

  expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
});

test("mark as done a todo which does not exist", () => {
  let todos = [
    "the thing i need to do",
    "water the plants",
    "find needle in the haystack",
  ];
  todos.forEach((todo) => execSync(todoTxtCli("add", `"${todo}"`)));

  let expected = "Error: todo #0 does not exist.";
  let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("done", "0")).toString("utf8");

  expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
});

test("mark as done without providing a todo number", () => {
  let todos = [
    "the thing i need to do",
    "water the plants",
    "find needle in the haystack",
  ];
  todos.forEach((todo) => execSync(todoTxtCli("add", `"${todo}"`)));

  let expected = "Error: Missing NUMBER for marking todo as done.";
  let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("done")).toString("utf8");

  expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
});

test("report pending & completed todos", () => {
  let todos = [
    "the thing i need to do",
    "water the plants",
    "find needle in the haystack",
  ];
  todos.forEach((todo) => execSync(todoTxtCli("add", `"${todo}"`)));

  execSync(todoTxtCli("done", "1"));
  execSync(todoTxtCli("done", "2"));

  let date = new Date();
  let expected = `${date.toISOString().slice(0, 10)} Pending : 1 Completed : 2`;
  let received = execSync(todoTxtCli("report")).toString("utf8");

  expect(received).toEqual(expect.stringContaining(expected));
});
```

Comment: Just from looking at the Expected and Received Strings from your tests, some todos end in a `.` and some do not. This could be your issue.

Comment: But why is the '.' coming it is not coming in the command line

Comment: Aren't there some chars such as \t or \r at the end?

Comment: @Ruli yeah there is a \n after every line but without it how will i be able to format the command line menu for line change.

Comment: @Ruli I used print() fxn in python which automatically changes line.

Comment: @GTBebbo after every line there is a '.' character added according to the npm test.But there is no '.' character when i run the script in command line,It is the same as expected output.

Comment: I would guess it has to do with unix and windows-like newline, they are different and can cause such problems, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Ruli Should i share wid u the code for my menu.Can u help me troubleshoot it.

Comment: @ShubhGaur edit the question and add it there if possible

Comment: wait im editing the question and also showing u the npm test code

Comment: @Ruli and others kindly respond